# Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\Form::__construct()

Tags: forms, symfony, service

I have got the following error when trying to use form as service in symfony 3:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\Form::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormConfigInterface,

I'm following this guide: https://www.supinfo.com/articles/single/737-service-symfony

It works perfectly with symfony 2 but not with symfony 3. Maybe there is new other way to manage it.

Comment: Post some code please. And service config too.

Comment: Hint: don't follow some random guide.  Follow the official docs.  Probably has to do with changes to the form option resolver.

Comment: Padam87, Cerard Thank you for answering.

Comment: These are some code:

Comment: #UserController.php

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * List contact
     *
     * @Route("/contact", name="contact")
     */

    public function contact(Request $request)
    {

 //Error comes when adding the code below
 //Calling service user.list

        $handler = $this->get('user.list');

Comment: #Resources/config/services.yml

   user.list:
        class: best_practice\WelcomeBundle\Handler\UserList
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager","@user.request","@user.form"]

    user.form:
        class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
        factory_service: form.factory
        factory_method: create
        arguments:
            - user
            - user.type

Comment: user.type:
        class: best_practice\WelcomeBundle\Form\UserType
        tags:
            - {name:form.type, alias:user.type}
    
    user.request:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack
        factory: ["@request_stack", getCurrentRequest]

Comment: #UserList.php 
class UserList extends Controller
{
    private $em;
    private $request;
    private $form;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $em, Request $request, Form $form)
    {
        $this->em=$em;
        $this->request=$request;
        $this->form=$form;
    }

Comment: #UserType.php
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name')->add('email');
    }/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'best_practice\WelcomeBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user.type';
    }
}

Comment: As you may have noticed, code in comments do not format well.  Update your original question with your code.  There is an edit link right underneath it.  No time limit of edits for questions.  And be sure to review the [official form docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_dependencies.html).